# Ran Composer Update on Laravel project, I have garbled text inside beginning of <body> tag

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a Laravel 5.2 project and needed to ran "composer update" to install and update some dependencies. It seemed to run fine, but at the very end the CLI output:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Bu1Scompapplg1Scomp+?appmoDDdutcӪ.'
                                   @? @ @ @
                                           E?DSDB ` @ @ @Generating optimized class loader
```

Now when I load **any** page (locally using MAMP), the body tag begins with a similar piece of garbled text to the above. If I remove my highest level layout completely, it's literally the only visible thing rendered on the page.

```
<body>
    Bud1�1Scompapplg1Scomp+�appmoDDdutcӪ.' @� @� @� @E�DSDB `� @� @� 
</body>
```

I can see it on any page loaded and as far as a search goes, it doesn't appear to be in any of the views. I've tried a search of the whole project for small pieces of the string but it returns nothing. Any idea where this might be being generated and why? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** it actually seems to be to do with running any artisan commands as it's the first thing output by the command. If I run just `php artisan` then it's the first thing output before it shows all the possible commands.

**My Solution:** was unable to find the root cause so I simply reverted the project to its previous state and manually installed the packages I needed.

Comment: I'd blow away your `vendor` directory and do a fresh `composer update`.

Comment: Could try that, but check the update I just made, seems to be to do with artisan. Is that still likely to have an effect?

Comment: It's best to do as @ceejayoz suggests. Better not waste time chasing some corrupted file.

Comment: @ceejayoz just gave that a try and it's still occurring.

Comment: @linuxartisan figured as much but gave it a go and it's still there.

Comment: @AdrianwithaW Drop your `composer.json` file contents into the question, please. I suspect you have a bad package somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -R compapp .` It should show corrupted file, then you can pin version of broken package in your composer.json. It's hard to say something more certain without seeing your composer.json.